# Parenthesis for reshape in numpy

Tags: numpy, formatting, reshape

```py
x = np.array([1, 2, 3])
print(x)

x.reshape((1, 3))
```

My question is: why are there two parenthesis in `((1, 3))`? When I write it like this:

```py
x.reshape(1, 3)
```

...the answer comes out the same. So why the two parenthesis?

Comment: `(1,3)` by itself is a `tuple`.  So `x.reshape((1,3))` is `reshape()` with a tuple argument.  `x.reshape(1,3)` has 2 arguments instead.  In learning to write Python functions you may have come across the option of writing a `def foo(args)` and `def foo(*args)`.  In case, follow the docs and don't try too hard to force consistency.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html):

> Unlike the free function numpy.reshape, this method on ndarray allows the elements of the shape parameter to be passed in as separate arguments.

So it's just a convenience. Almost everywhere else in NumPy, e.g. `np.ones((2,3))`, it's more usual to pass shapes with the parentheses around the shape tuple. In fact, I can't think of anywhere else!